# Shapiro test: is.numeric (x) is not TRUE

Tags: r, numeric, normal-distribution

I have problems with the `shapiro.test` function to check normality. I keep getting the error

```
is.numeric (x) is not TRUE
```

I use the following dataset (name: `Abund2014layer`):

```
Abundance
0.91567
0.01256
...
0.85605
```

which goes on for 75 rows.

I implement it as follows:

```
shapiro.test(Abund2014layer)
```

But I keep getting the error. The input should be a numeric vector of data values, I don't see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the data you are providing to `shapiro.test` a vector? If it is a `data.frame` then it will return this error. Try using `shapiro.test(Abund2014layer$Abundance)`

If you still get the error, you can see what `class` your vector is by using the `class(Abund2014layer$Abundance)` function. If it is not numeric, you can transform it and perform the Shapiro test in one line as follows;

`shapiro.test( as.numeric( Abund2014layer$Abundance ) )`